# GHC stuck due to UndecidableSuperClasses - expected behaviour or bug?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families, constraint-kinds, undecidable-instances

The following snippet makes GHC (checked with 8.6.2 & 8.4.4) stuck during compilation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableSuperClasses #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

data T = T

type family F t (c :: * -> Constraint) :: Constraint
type instance F T c = c T

class F t C => C t where

t :: C T => t
t = undefined
```

I think that it gets stuck because for `t` GHC tries to find `C T`, which leads to `F T C` which expands via type family `F` back to `C T`, which is what it was looking for (infinite loop).

I suppose that theoretically GHC could tell that it reached its quest for `C T` from itself and that anything that depends on itself can work fine recursively, or am I misunderstanding something?

Side note: in the real example where I stumbled upon this behaviour I was able to achieve what I wanted without the compiler being stuck by replacing `UndecidableSuperClasses` with [`Data.Constraint.Dict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10.1/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Dict) instead.

Comment: Can you show us the real example? I imagine its structure is more interesting than this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UndecidableSuperClasses` does *not* make instance resolution lazy. The compiler will still expand superclass constraints as far as possible. I believe that the fields in instance dictionaries that point to the superclass dictionaries are *strict*, and GHC actually pins them down at compile time. This is in contrast to `UndecidableInstances`, which allows *instance constraints* to be treated (a bit) lazily.

```
deriving instance Show (f (Fix f)) => Show (Fix f)
```

will work just fine. When resolving an instance for, e.g., `Show (Fix Maybe)`), GHC will see that it needs `Show (Maybe (Fix Maybe))`. It then sees it needs `Show (Fix Maybe)` (which it's currently resolving) and accept that thanks to `UndecidableInstances`.

All `UndecidableSuperClases` does is disable the checks that guarantee that expansion won't loop. See the bit near the beginning of [Ed Kmett's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=171&v=ZL9ehIJhk98) where he describes the process "reaching a fixed point".

Consider a working example (ripped from `Data.Constraint.Forall`):

```
type family Skolem (p :: k -> Constraint) :: k
class p (Skolem p) => Forall (p :: k -> Constraint)
```

GHC only accepts this with `UndecidableSuperclasses`. Why? Because it doesn't know anything about what that constraint might mean. As far as it knows, it could be the case that `p (Skolem p)` will reduce to `Forall p`. And that could actually happen!

```
class Forall P => P x

-- This definition loops the type checker
foo :: P x => x
foo = undefined
```